# How to toggle dynamically created div 's on the basis of class and name attributes, modified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Following is my reference Code:

```
$('#main_div').on('click','.gclass', function(){        
    $(this).css('color','#0088cc'); 
    if($(this).next().hasClass('gclass2') || $(this).next().next().hasClass('gclass3')){
        console.log('1st child or 2nd child');          
        $(this).parent().find('.gclass2,.gclass3').slideToggle();
    }   
    return false;
});
```

I have created two divs dynamically who are having same class '.gclass'.
When I click on '.gclass' then divs with '.gclass2 and .gclass3' are toggle.

When I click on one div of class .gclass then other div having .gclass is also getting toggled, which I dont want to.

Any hint please.

For CSS I tried :

```
 $(".gclass").not(this).css("color", "#6e6e6e");
```

But for **slideToggle()** what can be done?

Comment: Can you add the html to see the structure of it?

Comment: The following works. http://jsfiddle.net/L5Eta/ - (this) is the object that got clicked, so no need to use `.parent()`. `$(this).find('.gclass2,.gclass3').slideToggle();`

Comment: $(this).parent().find('.gclass2,.gclass3').slideToggle("slow"); this is not working.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/IjaboNE/3/edit this is my html structure. But I am doing this dynamically . This reference link is having static HTML structure. If I increase or decrease items in each div then how to tackle this for slideToggle?

Comment: @Nicolas Marengo : I done changes in divs as per your example. It is working Fine for me now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `slideToggle()` you can write custom filter that will filter out your element:

```
var that = this;
$(this).parent().find('.gclass2,.gclass3').filter(function() {
    return $(this).prev()[0] === that || $(this).prev().prev()[0] === that
}).slideToggle();
```

Working example see here: http://jsbin.com/IjaboNE/1/edit

Comment: Thank you. But I will be changing no. of items for each Div. So in that case what I can be done?

Comment: @eegloo Your DOM structure suffer from several issues: 1. both `gclass` and `gclassN` (where N is number) are on the same level and there is nothing that wraps each group; 2. there is no shared class between all `gclassN` elements. Solving this issues will make your life much more easier. However there is a solution for your case as well http://jsbin.com/IjaboNE/6/edit

Comment: I have done some changes in DOM. div.gclass is parent div and other div.gclassN are children for div.gclass. So with "http://jsfiddle.net/L5Eta/" My project requirement is resolved. Actually I want to do this with divs on same level. Your answer is also good. Thanks a lot.